# Django channels and socket.io-client

Tags: django, socket.io

I'm trying to use them for the first time and wonder I'm headed to the right direction.

Here are my understandings,

socket.io is a wrapper around websocket, and falls back to sub-optimal solutions when websocket is not available.

Django channels can talk websocket as well.
(I think it converts django as a message queue like system. although this understanding or misunderstanding should affect this question)

So I'm trying to use Django channels on the server and socket.io-client on the client.

socket.io has api which looks like

`socket.on(type, (payload)=> {})`

Whereas Django channels has a form of

`message.reply_channel.send({
   "text": json
})`

is the "text" `type` of `socket.on(type)`?

Can Django channels and socket.io-client talk to each other?

Comment: Use channels 2. Don't use channels 1, it is not supported and will never be supported again.

Comment: you can use django-channels with socketio as the consumer, and route socketio traffic to socketio server. check this out https://github.com/ly3too/django-channels-with-socket.io

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the Socket.IO README:

> Note: Socket.IO is not a WebSocket implementation. Although Socket.IO indeed uses WebSocket as a transport when possible, it adds some metadata to each packet: the packet type, the namespace and the ack id when a message acknowledgement is needed. That is why a WebSocket client will not be able to successfully connect to a Socket.IO server, and a Socket.IO client will not be able to connect to a WebSocket server (like ws://echo.websocket.org) either. Please see the protocol specification [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol).

So, you shouldn't expect Channels to work directly with Socket.IO. [Global browser support for websockets is at 93%](https://caniuse.com/#search=websockets), which is probably high enough to just use the [websocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) directly.

Answer (score 9):

To quote the [creator of django channels](https://www.aeracode.org/): https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1038

> Channels doesn't support socket.io - it's a different protocol that isn't websockets or HTTP but layers on top of them. You'll have to use a socket.io server if you want to use it.